# Determine first available number

Tags: c++, c++17

So what I want to do is determine the first value that is not in a vector. for example if i had a vector like this

```
std::vector<unsigned int> s = {10, 9, 7, 1, 3};
```

I would want 2.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any guarantee of how large the values in the vector can be? How often will you be doing this? Just once? Or will you then add that new number to the vector and continue doing it repeatedly? Also, what have you tried so far and where'd you get stuck?

Comment: I assume "*first value*" is supposed to mean "*first positive integer*"?

Comment: Through the application I won't really know how many times the function to do this will be called.

Comment: Sort it first `std::sort`.. then go through it from low to high and see which is missing.

Comment: place the values in a `std::set` and look for values starting from `1` (or the value you want start from).

Comment: What do you mean "first value"? In `{10, 9, 4}` What is the first value not in vector? Is it `1`? Is it `3`? Or `5`? How about in `{10, 9, 4 -3}`? Please try and give a more formal definition of what you require

Comment: Depending on the range you are working with you can also achieve this with Counting Sort.

Comment: @bolov i would want to pick 42 first

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 and you would be wrong. `42` is the last answer ever.

Comment: @bolov what i wan't is 1 probably and the vector will never use negetive numbers

Comment: @grimofender "probably"? What do you mean "probably"?

Comment: @grimofender next time first try yourself **then** if you have trouble post a question with a specific issue.

Comment: Just iterate between min and max and exit at first one that doesn't exist in the vector.

Comment: I guess that's true I was being kind of lazy. i'm a try harder before posting questions on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Brute force:** Use loops

```
for (int number=1; number< s.size(); ++number) {
   bool found = false;
   for (int i=0;i < s.size(); ++i) {
        if (s[i] == number) found = true;
   }
   if (!found) return number;
}
```

This has quadratic complexity which is probably not that relevant for 5 elements, but also it is not nice code.

**Less brute Force:** Sorting

Once you sorted the numbers you just have to start from the beginning until a number is missing:

```
 std::sort(s.begin(),s.end());
 if (s[0] != 1) return 1;
 int number = 1;
 for (int i=1;i<s.size();++i) {
     if (s[i] != number && s[i] != number+1) return number+1;
     number = s[i];
 }
```

**Better**

The optimal way to do something is to not do it. Where are the numbers coming from? How do you fill the vector? Can't you already determine the first missing number while you popoulte the array?

**PS**

The code above assumes the vector is not empty and contains only numbers `>= 1`.

Comment: first +1 well designed i'ma try this one

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<unsigned int> s = {10, 9, 7, 1, 3};
    set<unsigned int> given_numbers;
    for(auto i:s)
        given_numbers.insert(i);
    int i=1;
    while(true){
        if(!given_numbers.count(i)){
            cout<<i<<endl;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `i` suppose to number? I'm not sure

Comment: @grimofender, Yes `i` is a number

Comment: It works but I found a better solution. nice job though =D